# Help needed in Visual studio project properties

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, clr

i hav a main project(ex: applicationsolution explorer (10projects)) which depend on 10 other

projects. in those in one project i need to use /clr(Common Language Runtime) option.As i know

/clr doesnot compatable with /mtd(in code genration property of linker section ) i changed to

/mdd. my question is

Do i need to enable /clr option for parent (aplication) also ? since i

am using /clr option in its dependent project.so i have to enble in parent projce also????

Give me ur support in this regard which helps me lot

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not at all needed.